# How to present "System is offline" for every page of a Digital Experience (AKA Community)?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, navigationmixin.navigate

We need an enable/disable feature that is more user friendly than the Activate/Deactivate of a Community. But the Community has many pages, so a mechanism that applies to all would be ideal.

One idea (not ideal) is to embed an invisible component in each layout that navigates to the offline page:

```
navigateIfOffline() {
    if (this.offline) {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: "comm__namedPage",
            attributes: {
                pageName: "offline"
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but I have not succeeded in getting that to fire at the right time. Is there a reliable technique (lifecycle method, event to listen to) to make this work?

Any other approaches to solve this problem?

Comment: When a community/site is deactivated doesn't the Visualforce `InMaintenance` page get shown to users?

Comment: Yes it does. But that does not fit the "user friendly" part of what we want. See first sentence of the question. A further factor that I didn't mention is also that we want to switch sets of users under specific Accounts off, rather than everyone.

Comment: I was going to suggest making a custom maintenance page, but your need to turn specific Accounts on and off would rule out that approach. I like the theme approach!

Comment: @nbrown Want to and need to are 2 different things... If I'd remembered that the maintenance page could be customised I would have looked at that first. Do post as an answer and I'll give it an upvote as it should be considered as an approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a site (formerly known as a community) is deactivated the "Inactive Site Home Page" is displayed in its place. This has to be a Visualforce page, but you can customize this page as you like. `InMaintenance` is an out-of-the-box placeholder that you can start with as a template for when your site is inactive.

The `InMaintenance` page looks like this by default:
[image: InMaintenance Visualforce page]

To set an Inactive Site Home Page:

1. Go to Setup > Digital Experiences > All Sites.
2. Open **Workspaces** for your site.
3. Go to **Administration**
4. Then **Pages** in the sidebar
5. Under **Advanced Customizations** click "Go to Force.com" where you're be taken to Site Details in classic.
6. Click "Edit" then set your **Inactive Site Home Page**.

[image: Editing your Site (see step 6)]

Answer (score 0):

More code than I expected but seems to work OK just in `connectedCallback`. This component that renders nothing is added to the theme layout header so it is present in every page.

```
export default class OfflineCheck extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    online;
    currentPageRef;

    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    pageRef(pageRef) {
        this.currentPageRef = pageRef;
        this.navigateIfReady();
    }

    async connectedCallback() {
        // A mechanism not described here to communicate offline
        const userContext = await getUserContext();
        this.online = userContext.configuration.cvcp__Enabled__c;
        this.navigateIfReady();
    }

    navigateIfReady() {

        // Not ready yet
        if (this.online === undefined || this.currentPageRef === undefined) return;

        // Online so nothing to do
        if (this.online) return;
        
        const currentPageName = this.currentPageRef.attributes.name;    // name here
        const offlinePageName = 'offline';

        // Avoid infinite loop
        if (currentPageName.toLowerCase() === offlinePageName.toLowerCase()) return;

        const destinationPageRef = {
            type: "comm__namedPage",
            attributes: {
                pageName: offlinePageName                               // pageName here
            }
        };
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](destinationPageRef);
    }
}
```